# MySQL, a little help with conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a products table with a stock field and a timestamp field that indicates the last time the product has been updated.

I need to write a query that pulls all the products that have stock>=0 and, for those that stock=0, to check if the difference between the timestamp and the current time is less than 30 days . If stock=0 and datediff(now(), timestamp)>30 then to exclude the products from the recordset.

So far I've written a query (see below) but it's incorrect as it will exclude even the products with stock>0 when they havent been updated in a the past 30 days.

```
select * from products where stock>=0 and datediff(now(), timestamp)>=30;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE stock > 0 OR stock = 0 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), timestamp) <= 30;
```

If `stock` field is unsigned, the condition 'stock = 0' can be removed.

Comment: wow, that completely missed me! It was THAT simple after all. Thanks mate.

Comment: came to post this... is this missing some parentheses around the OR conditions?

Comment: I might suggest parens around the conditions after the `OR` for readability sake (i.e. for those of us who don't like to have to remember the precedence of `OR` and `AND` ^_^)...

Comment: @Randy, @bash, `AND` has higher [precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operator-precedence.html) than `OR`, so there's nothing wrong with the query.

Comment: Yes, I had to change the query a bit to make it work but I got the idea:

SELECT * FROM products where ((stock > 0) or (stock=0 and DATEDIFF(NOW(), timestamp) <= 30))

Comment: @jswolf19 ahhh sorry I always put parenthesis around different operators to make them less cryptic to read so I never worried much about the precedence between `AND` and `OR`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

As per your comment, here is the answer
very cryptic question

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE stock > 0 
OR (stock = 0 and DATEDIFF(NOW(), timestamp) <= 30);
```

Comment: The point is to get the products with stock=0 too but that have been updated recently (during tha past 30 days). To get the bigger picture, we have a time margin of 30 days to consider a product discontinued and the period begins when the stock is set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE 
        stock>0 
OR (
        stock=0
        AND datediff(now(), timestamp)<=30
);
```

Comment: @Randy, You mean because the comparison on the date is the wrong direction so you know it's not correct?